# Angular push single object into array

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a component for search my employee table. I have a dropdown list that is hooked up to my service and as you type, it updates the options to select from.

My issue I run into is when the record set is narrowed down enough to only provide a single result. Since I am calling a `.map` function in here, it breaks when we are no longer checking an array, and instead, a single object.

My goal here is that when a single object is detected, I simply push that into an array, leaving me an array of a single object.

```
 this._mapsService.searchEmployees(searchString)
                .then((results: EmployeeRecord[]) => {

                    // No Results Found
                    if(typeof(results) === undefined){
                        console.log('No Results')

                    // Single record, add object to array
                    }else if(!this._utils.isArray(results)){
                        console.log('here');
                        (results: EmployeeRecord[]) => Array(results)
                    }

                    this.employeeSelection.items = results.map(result => {
                        return new EmployeeOption(result.QID, result.FirstName + ' ' + result.LastName + ' (' + result.NTID + ')')
                    });

                    (<any>this.employeeSelection).open()
                })
```

Referenced utility service:

```
/**
 * Determine if the obj provided is an array
 * 
 * @param {*} obj 
 * @returns 
 * @memberof UtilsService
 */
isArray(obj: any) {
    return Array.isArray(obj)
}
```

My issue is occurring in the line with the comment `// Single record, add object to array`. I am trying to push my object into an array. I see it his the `console.log` function but I then keep getting an error regarding the `.map` so I know that the results were not put into an array as expected.

What am I missing here?

**Update:**

Service Call

```
/**
 * Search the employee table for data
 * 
 * @returns 
 * @memberof MapsService
 */
searchEmployees(query) {
    // Minimum of 2 characters required for search
    if(query.length >= 2){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this._http.post(this.baseUrlGlobal + '/fetchEmployeesAPI', { "query": query}, { "headers": this.headers })
                .map((result: Response) => result.json())
                .subscribe((results) => resolve(results.results));
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Why not model as an array to begin with? That way, whether you have one item, or a hundred, you'll still be dealing with an array regardless.

Comment: @SBB you want to keep adding the values to the array like a immutable object is that so ?

Comment: @Muirik - Thats a good point. I will see what I can do with that

Comment: @RahulSingh That is correct, I want to keep pushing my results received back into this array that I can then run my .map function over.

Comment: why not use a shared service as model object and keep adding to that ?

Comment: Given my current service call, how could I do that ?